# Page transitions

Tags: 7

I am interested in using https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions for page transitons in Drupal 7.

I am not a coder but have some experience with setting up Drupal sites with themes from Theme Forest.

I want different on-page links or menu links to have different transitions and if the user clicks back it reverses the transition.

Answer (score 0):

1) Load the javascript library into your theme. (put it in your themes javascript folder and then see [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/304255) for help loading it)

Because Drupal is not a static website you will have to do some work to get page transitions working the way you would like. Furthermore, it is always so simple to add code to dynamically generated menus.

You have three ways someone will navigate.

1) Links manually created inside node or region content - These are easy, just add the transition to the `a` tag.

2) Menus - This are a little tricky. You either need to write some jQuery or Javascript to manipulate the DOM or write a theme pre-proecess template as noted [here](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/adding-custom-markup-drupal-menu-items). I would try the template option first as it will be the most reliable solution and shouldn't be too hard to implement, even for an inexperienced coder.

3) User's browser buttons - For these the most reliable way I am aware of to capture browser behavior is with JavaScript or jQuery. This is not that difficult, but you will have to enact the page transitions within jQuery as there will not be any page event to fire off. This will require you parse the DOM to learn which transition you should use or pass it in a get parameter to pickup on page load.

Last, you say you want to "reverse" the transition. If this is not already built into this library, you will have to dig into the code to figure out how to make that happen.